# How can Document Uploader set approval task due date

Tags: workflow

I have a need for the uploader of a document to set the approval task "due date" after he publishes the document. There will be multiple approvers, hence I am using a workflow created using Sharepoint Designer.
Ideally he should be able to specify the due date, so that this can be included in the mail that goes out to the approvers.
any ideas as to how can this be done, will be greatly appreciated.

Ajey